# ValueError: unsupported format character ''' using psycopg2 with a LIKE query

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask

Im having some trouble with a query using psycopg2. i want the user to input a search query and search the database. using it in pgadmin4 works as expected but when I try to use it in flask I get the error
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' . My quess is because of the %% between the input. is there any way to bypass that given my current code??  any ideas please?

Flask

```
@app.route("/search_query", methods=["POST","GET"])
def search_query():
    PART_NUMBER = request.form["PART_NUMBER"]
    query = ''' SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE '%%s%'; '''
    cur.execute(query,(PART_NUMBER,))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    return render_template("search.html", data0=result)
```

Pgadmin Query

```
SELECT * FROM inventory
WHERE part_number LIKE '%whatever I need to search%';
```

all my other queries work fine

```
query = '''SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE id = %s;'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include a literal % you need to double it. Try it this way:

```
query = ''' SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE '%%%s%%'; '''
```

EDIT:

Strange if PART_NUMBER is string one has to move the %-Wildcards to the argument, careful, maybe this opens some SQL-Injection vulnerabilities.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres     password=docker host=localhost port=5432")

cur = conn.cursor()

def search_query():
    PART_NUMBER = 'IAW'
    query = ''' SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE %s ; '''
    cur.execute(query,('%{}%'.format(PART_NUMBER),))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()

search_query()
```

Comment: i though of that but i get this error 

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "IAW"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE '%'IAW'%;
^

Comment: Ahh, ok you are right, when I tried it I used a int as PART_NUMBER which works, if it is a string it fails. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround like this, dont know if its good but it works. i would like to hear of a better way from anyone more experienced !

```
@app.route("/search_query", methods=["POST","GET"])
def search_query():
    PART_NUMBER = request.form["PART_NUMBER"]
    query = ''' SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE PART_NUMBER LIKE %s '''
    pattern = '%{}%'.format(PART_NUMBER)
    cur.execute(query,(pattern,))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    return render_template("search.html", data0=result)
```